# disconnect the old SSID and connect to new SSID

Tags: wifi

We recenlty setup 802.x wireless setup and create a new ssid, our windows user are still connected to old ssid, we want to force the setting to connect to new ssid, is it possible to connect the windows laptop to join the new ssid automatically, which we dont want the client to connect the old ssid.

is this possible to achieve using group policy or sccm 2012, we are running both services also

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use Group Policy to configure wireless as outlined here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg266419.aspx